# Show histogram in Python from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, histogram

I read dataframe from csv file. One column contains year (sample: 1900) or '' of peoples' birthday.
How can I show histogarm of the column in Python 3?

Comment: This would help [pandas.Series.hist](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html) ?

Comment: Agree with John Galt, you can just call `.hist()` on the column e.g. `df['year'].hist()` or whatever your column is named

Comment: I created the column from other and seems, because the creating next error was shown `"TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()"` When I save table with new created columns and read to new dataftame, `.hist()` works.

Comment: now I need show histogram for 2 columns (year and gender).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {'gender' : Series(['M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M']),'year' : Series([1900, 1910, 1920, 1920, 1920])}
df = DataFrame(d)

grouped = df.groupby('gender').year
grouped.plot(kind='hist',legend=True)
```